# Laravel valet secure does not work and where is nginx information coming from after deletion?

Tags: laravel, nginx, composer-php, laravel-valet, valet

So I am working on Laravel/Valet, I was trying to use ssl. So I ran:

```
valet secure examplesite
```

This did not work. I have uninstalled valet, cleared cache, remove laravel/valet. Nothing worked. I just could not open the https://examplesite.test site. However, the non-secure http site is working fine.

**Question 1**: How can I get this to work? I am on MAC OS Sierra.

**Question 2:** Even after removing nginx and valet, I am still seeing something like the image shown [image: like this image] when I load the page. Where is the information about the server nginx coming from?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you restart your pc? I faced this type of problem. But after restart pc Its works. Before doing this, check valet status and check ngnix configuration again.

Comment: Of course, restarting the pc may work. But you don't have to. You can just restart the Nginx server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So after running valet secure in the same directory of the web project;

I ran the code below:

```
    sudo nginx -s stop && sudo nginx
```

Comment: I tried all kind of valet commands, reinstalls, re-links, re-secures... and nothing worked. But just running nginx as sudo did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10 users:

**Step 1:**
Open cmd in administrator (sudo equivalent of linux)

**Step 2:**
`valet stop` if valet is already running

**Step 3:**
cd into your project directory (this is the most important step)

**Step 4:**
`valet secure`

**Step 5:**
`valet start`